# Formatting numbers with thousand separator as empty string on amcharts4

Tags: amcharts

I need to format the chart number format so that numbers stop looking like that 1,525 (comma separator) and start looking like this **1 525 (empty string thousand separator)**. Plus, I need dot separator for decimal, but only if a number has any, like this 1 525.4
The closest number format I was able to find for amCharts4 version is

```
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '#,###.#';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a research I've found a solution - you have to use [locales](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/locales/).

This line of code helped me a lot:

```
chart.language.locale = am4lang_[locale];
```

For empty string separator I used am4lang_ru_RU.

Btw, if you need to make your own number, strings, etc formatting, you can create [your locales](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-translations/) for that.